# How to get input value of TextField from Material UI without using onChange event?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I tried to use `this.refs.myField.getValue()` or `this.refs.myTextField.input.value`. But, they are depreciated.

I don't want to use `onChange` inside `TextField`, I just convert the text when clicking button Convert

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: '',
    };
  };

  handleConvertString = (event) => {
    let str = this.refs.myField.getValue();
    this.setState({
      text: str.replace(/[dog]/gi, ''),
    })
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          ref="myField"
          fullWidth
        />
        <Button variant="outlined" href="#outlined-buttons" onClick={this.handleConvertString}>
          Convert
        </Button>
        <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
      </div>
    )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [MUI text field API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/).

You are trying to access the underlying value of the text area, so you need the ref of the HTML DOM element.

For the text area, use:

```
<TextField
  inputRef={ref => { this.inputRef = ref; }}
  fullWidth
/>
```

And then in your method access the value with `this.inputRef.value`.

Comment: Emphasize: You have to use `inputRef`. Not just `ref`.

Answer (score 3):

```
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm(); 
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmit)}>
              <label>
                
              <TextField
                  id="outlined-basic"
                  label="email"
                  name="email"
                  fullWidth
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputRef={register}
                  required
                />
              </label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <br />
                
                <TextField
                  id="outlined-secondary:cyan"
                  label="password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  fullWidth
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputRef={register}
                  required
                />
              </label>

              <br />
              <br />

              <Button
                className={classes.root}
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                fullWidth
                type="submit"
              >
                Login
              </Button>
             
            </form>
```

> Then handling it with :

```
const formSubmit = (data) => {
    // Post Data
    const postData = {
      email: data.email,
      pass: data.password,
    };

    console.log(data)
```

Comment: For clarity, `useForm()` is a hook defined in the `react-hook-form` package. See https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform

Note that there is a breaking change in the latest version of `react-hook-form`. You'll need to modify the above code based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/66935286/4573050