# Getting Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function in react

Tags: react-hook-form

I'm trying to do validations for my form in react. I chose "react-hook-form" library. But I'm constantly getting error "Path.split is not a function. Even after using the default example given in their website, I'm getting the same error.
This is the default code given in the official site.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  console.log(watch("example")); // watch input value by passing the name of it

  return (
    {/* "handleSubmit" will validate your inputs before invoking "onSubmit" */}
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    {/* register your input into the hook by invoking the "register" function */}
      <input name="example" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />
      
      {/* include validation with required or other standard HTML validation rules */}
      <input name="exampleRequired" ref={register({ required: true })} />
      {/* errors will return when field validation fails  */}
      {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Hi @ArunKumarMohan Here is the link "https://codesandbox.io/live/ljesmy8"

Comment: Looks like you've shared a session URL instead of a CodeSandbox URL. I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66927781/3724716) that should fix the issue. Replace `ref={register}` with `{...register('example')}`.

Comment: Yeah its working. Thanks @ArunKumarMohan. I didn't see migration docs.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

react-hook-form updated to 7.0.0 from 6.X.X and has breaking changes:

You have to replace all `ref={register}` with `{...register('value_name')}`

### **Example:**

Version 6.X.X:

```
<input ref={register({ required: true })} name="test" />
```

Version 7.0.X:

```
<input {...register('test', { required: true })} />
```

Comment: You could run the codemon `npx @hookform/codemod v7/update-register`

Comment: @Ethaan how do you execute the command with yarn?

Comment: @Twirlman the `npx` command will still work even if you are using yarn.

Comment: yea as @BraydenW says, `npx` come with `npm 5.2+`

Comment: let suppose we have any reusable input field them how we will pass this register to that reusable function

Comment: @Ethaan codemon comment needs to be added to the solution. Big time saver.

Answer (score 27):

Simple input with `required` and `errors.message` features, necessary changes in update:

From version 6.x.x:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (values) => {...};

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          name="message"
          autoComplete="off"
          ref={register({
            required: "Required",
          })}
        />
        {errors.message && errors.message.message}
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To version 7.x.x:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }} = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (values) => {...};

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          name="message"
          autoComplete="off"
          {...register("message", {
            required: "Required",
          })}
        />
        {errors.message && errors.message.message}
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In addition to register fix, if you use errors from `useForm()`, now `errors` feature is exported from `formState`.

Answer (score 19):

Worth mentioning that if you are using `material ui` or something similar, where `ref={ref}` throws an error (because it expects a different prop name instead of `ref`), you might want to

```
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';


return (
 <TextField {...register('name')} />
)
```

there is a migration guide for this [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases), but still worth to mention

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, there are changes to how `register` is to be used in `v7`

If you are still getting errors, ensure that `id` is actually a `string` and not any other type such as a number.

```
   <input {...register(id)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
export default function App() {
const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
   <input {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
   {errors.firstName?.type === 'required' && "First name is required"}
  
   <input {...register("lastName", { required: true })} />
   {errors.lastName && "Last name is required"}
  
   <input type="submit" />
  </form>
 );
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is giving errors