# ref={register} inside <input> is giving me a path.split error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to make a form with React and when I put

`ref={register}` inside

```
<input className="form-control" ref={register} type="text" name="text" id="text" />
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: path.split is not a function
get
src/utils/get.ts:6
```

Any suggestions? I'm following [this guy's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRRA-SrNyxg) youtube tutorial:

Here is the code above my return () statement:

```
 export const CreateTodo = () => {
        const { register, handleSubmit} = useForm(); 
    
        const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

return ( ... );
}
```

[CodeSandbox link:](https://codesandbox.io/s/pathsplit-error-2fwdt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you share a minimal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan ok I have shared a CodeSandbox link

Answer (score 8):

The way to register inputs has changed in react-hook-form v7.0.0 (the version you're using).

From the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7),

> `register` method is no longer occurred at `ref`, instead invoke the function itself and spread the props into the input. The function itself will return the following props: `onChange`, `onBlur`, name and `ref`.
>
> ```
> - <input ref={register({ required: true })} name="test" />
> + <input {...register('name', { required: true })} /> 
> + <TextInput {...register('name', { required: true })} />
> ```

```
<input
  className="form-control"
  {...register('text')}
  type="text"
/>
```

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]

Answer (score 0):

According  to new Version (7.x.x) You have to pass the register Like this

<input {...register('test', { required: true })} />

in 6.x.x it was like

<input inputref={register('test', { required: true })} />