# Can't resolve TypeError: path.split is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm following a Next.js/Firebase course from Fireship and I'm running into some issues. This is the error I see 'in' `localhost:3000/admin/my-first-article`:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: path.split is not a function

Call Stack
get
node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.mjs (33:0)
register
node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.mjs (1850:0)
commitAttachRef
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (23543:0)
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (23401:0)
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24578:0)
commitLayoutEffects_begin
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24564:0)
commitLayoutEffects
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24502:0)
commitRootImpl
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26779:0)
commitRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26638:0)
finishConcurrentRender
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25937:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25765:0)
workLoop
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (533:0)
```

### Some more details

I'm using the `react-hook-form` npm package and I need to set a `ref` attribute on an input tag. However, I keep getting this error: [link to Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9anXo.jpg). I'm *not* using TypeScript. I *do not think* it's a TypeScript error. **(Update: I have an `.eslintrc.json` file. Could that be related? I don't have a lot of knowledge yet about ESLint)**

**Good to know:** I found this Stack Overflow answer but unfortunately, the solution that I found in that article did **not** resolve mine :( ([Getting Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927051/getting-uncaught-typeerror-path-split-is-not-a-function-in-react))

So the errors I'm experiencing are actually two-fold. On the one hand I'm getting the 'path.split is not a function' error and on the other the error with the `ref` attribute. I think they're somehow related, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it could be. I *think* the error *could* be in either `/pages/admin/[slug].js` or `/pages/admin/index.js`.

GitHub repository (up to date): https://github.com/YinChuRijnaard/dev.chu

Thank you for your time, and for helping out a noob!!! :)

Comment: I haven't used react-hook-form, but it looks like `register` is being used incorrectly. Maybe try the following in the PostForm component: `<textarea {...register("content")} />` AND `<input {...register("published")} type="checkbox" />`. That will pass in the necessary form props, like `name`, into each element.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen k

Comment: @StaffordRose, update: it seemed to have worked. I have no idea why this works though :'). Hopefully it doesn't break any of my other code when I continue the tutorial. Thank you for your help, once again!

Comment: @YinChu You're welcome! It shouldn't break anything. If you look at the docs it helps explain how `register` works: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register